# ANTLR - NoViableAltException

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr

I'm trying to learn ANTLR by writing a grammer (I'm using eclipse with the plugins for ANTLR), and it was going alright until I ran into the error:

```
NoViableAltException: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
```

When I try to test my args parser rule;

```
typedident  :   (INT|CHAR) IDENT;

args    :   (typedident ( COMMA typedident)*)?;
```

An ident is a letter followed by any character, this works, I've tested it. typedident also works for the test.

I'm using the input of `int a12q2efwe, char a12eqdsf` (totally random) and the tree appears fine in the interpreter, the only problem is that args has four branches instead of 3, typedident, comma, typedident and then the error in the last one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If an `IDENT` must start with a letter, then the input `"12eqdsf"` is no `IDENT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the built-in interpreter. Don't, it's buggy. Either create a custom test-class yourself, or use ANTLRWorks' debugger (I believe the Eclipse plugin uses the same debugger as ANTLRWorks). Just never use the interpreter.

In ANTLRWorks, the input `"int a12q2efwe, char eq45dsf"` is being parsed (using the debugger) as follows:

[image]

As you can see yourself using this small grammar:

```
grammar T;

args       : (typedident (COMMA typedident)*)? EOF;
typedident : (INT | CHAR) IDENT;

COMMA : ',';
INT   : 'int';
CHAR  : 'char';
IDENT : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')*;
SPACE : ' ' {skip();};
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this answer will help you:

[ANTLR NoViableAltException with JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702048/antlr-noviablealtexception-with-java)

According to it a `EOF` token is missing in your grammar. You did show us the complete grammar, didn't you?

Comment: Nope, the problem here is definitely not the absence of an `EOF` (nor does the Q&A you linked to imply it!).

Comment: In my understanding of the accepted answer the problem were multiple EOF tokens in the wrong places but it should have been one EOF in the entry rule. The questioner's entry rule `args` does not have an EOF.

Comment: @BartKiers: Ups, I didn't look at the author, I assumed the first comment came from the questioner. I fixed my comment. Besides of this: Your own answer implies to me that there _should_ be an EOF.

Comment: Yes, the answer suggests to put an `EOF` at the end of the entry of the grammar. But like I said: the absence of `EOF` will *not* produce such an error. Did you see the answer you're talking about is mine? :)

Comment: @BartKiers: No, I did not see it. :-))) I think I should shut up right now :-(

Comment: I believe you may be right, the entire grammar is a fair bit larger and when I wrote a test for the entire thing at once it didn't happen. So...yeah, it was just me being an idiot and not realising I have to test the entire thing at once.
Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Incredidave, you can test the entire grammar at once, or just the single rule, but the problem is not the absence of `EOF`, believe me. To be able to properly unit-test your parser (and lexer!), you really should test separate rules.

Comment: @Incredidave: Looking at Bart's expertise on the complete ANTLR subject I really recommend to listen to him carefully.